# Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod network

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, flannel

Issue Redis POD creation on k8s(v1.10) cluster and POD creation stuck at "ContainerCreating"

```
Type     Reason                  Age                   From                Message
  ----     ------                  ----                  ----                -------
  Normal   Scheduled               30m                   default-scheduler   Successfully assigned redis to k8snode02
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume   30m                   kubelet, k8snode02  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-f8tcg"
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  5m (x1202 over 30m)   kubelet, k8snode02  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "redis_default" network: failed to find plugin "loopback" in path [/opt/loopback/bin /opt/cni/bin]
  Normal   SandboxChanged          47s (x1459 over 30m)  kubelet, k8snode02  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

Comment: Do you have `/etc/cni/net.d` and its `/opt/cni/bin` friend, as shown in the [flannel cni repo](https://github.com/coreos/flannel-cni/tree/v0.3.0#readme)?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel 
Yes, I do have in the master node.
`[root@k8smaster01 k8s]# cd /etc/cni/net.d/
[root@k8smaster01 net.d]# ls
**10-flannel.conf**


[root@k8smaster01 net.d]# cd /opt/cni/bin
[root@k8smaster01 bin]# ls
**bridge  dhcp  flannel  host-local  ipvlan  loopback  macvlan  portmap  ptp  sample  tuning  vlan**`

Comment: Sure, but do you have it on _all_ the Nodes, specifically `k8snode02` which doesn't _sound_ like a master Node? An SDN-based cluster requires that **all** participants are able to use the SDN

Comment: I don't find /opt/cni/bin directory in k8snode02, So how can I get those SDN's onto k8snode02. Should I need to copy the CNI bin files? or how can i fix this.

Comment: I also see the k8snode02 in "NOT READY" state.
`NAME          STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
k8smaster01   Ready      master    20d       v1.10.4
k8snode01     Ready      <none>    20d       v1.10.4
k8snode02     NotReady   <none>    20d       v1.10.4`

Comment: Well, how did you get them on your master Node? And did you follow the link I provided, since that repo is _nothing but_ how to distribute those files across your cluster?

Comment: I see CNI files got removed accidentally by other users and that created this issue. Finally able to fix the issue and thanks a lot for your guidance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ensure that `/etc/cni/net.d` and its `/opt/cni/bin` friend both exist and are correctly populated with the [CNI](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni#readme) configuration files and binaries on *all Nodes*. For flannel specifically, one might make use of the [flannel cni repo](https://github.com/coreos/flannel-cni/tree/v0.3.0#readme)

Comment: I am facing same issue. exist both path. i am using calico network

Comment: Error is : Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "b577ddbdd5fbd6cbe79e5b1bf20648e981590ecd0df545a0158ce909d9179096" network for pod "frontend-784f75ddb7-nbz7t": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "frontend-784f75ddb7-nbz7t_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/

Comment: Don't overlook the **are correctly populated** part. For that `/var/lib/calico/nodename` error specifically, be careful if you are using a `DaemonSet` to configure calico: k8s may try to schedule that `frontend` Pod on the Node before the `DaemonSet` has finished configuring it. In that specific circumstance, just deleting all the Pods from the Node after calico is successfully configured will cure that sandbox problem

Comment: Thank for quick reply ... Had firewall issue. getting warning ````Warning  BackOff         2m11s (x153 over 36m)  kubelet, truecomtelesoft  Back-off restarting failed container````
should i ignore this ?

Comment: @mdaniel, by "just deleting all the Pods from the Node after calico is successfully configured will cure that sandbox problem". You mean "all" pods from all the workers or  only the woker that the `frontend` pod is on?

Answer (score 9):

When I used calico as CNI and I faced a similar issue.

The container remained in creating state, I checked for /etc/cni/net.d and /opt/cni/bin on master both are present but not sure if this is required on worker node as well.

```
root@KubernetesMaster:/opt/cni/bin# kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-5c7588df-5zds6   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          21m
root@KubernetesMaster:/opt/cni/bin# kubectl get nodes
NAME               STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kubernetesmaster   Ready    master   26m   v1.13.4
kubernetesslave1   Ready    <none>   22m   v1.13.4
root@KubernetesMaster:/opt/cni/bin#

kubectl describe pods
Name:               nginx-5c7588df-5zds6
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               kubernetesslave1/10.0.3.80
Start Time:         Sun, 17 Mar 2019 05:13:30 +0000
Labels:             app=nginx
                    pod-template-hash=5c7588df
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/nginx-5c7588df
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-qtfbs (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-qtfbs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-qtfbs
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From                       Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----                       -------
  Normal   Scheduled               18m                    default-scheduler          Successfully assigned default/nginx-5c7588df-5zds6 to kubernetesslave1
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "123d527490944d80f44b1976b82dbae5dc56934aabf59cf89f151736d7ea8adc" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "8cc5e62ebaab7075782c2248e00d795191c45906cc9579464a00c09a2bc88b71" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "30ffdeace558b0935d1ed3c2e59480e2dd98e983b747dacae707d1baa222353f" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "630e85451b6ce2452839c4cfd1ecb9acce4120515702edf29421c123cf231213" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "820b919b7edcfc3081711bb78b79d33e5be3f7dafcbad29fe46b6d7aa22227aa" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "abbfb5d2756f12802072039dec20ba52f546ae755aaa642a9a75c86577be589f" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "dfeb46ffda4d0f8a434f3f3af04328fcc4b6c7cafaa62626e41b705b06d98cc4" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "9ae3f47bb0282a56e607779d3267127ee8b0ae1d7f416f5a184682119203b1c8" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "546d07f1864728b2e2675c066775f94d658e221ada5fb4ed6bf6689ec7b8de23" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Normal   SandboxChanged          18m (x12 over 18m)     kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m39s (x829 over 18m)  kubelet, kubernetesslave1  (combined from similar events): Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "f586be437843537a3082f37ad139c88d0eacfbe99ddf00621efd4dc049a268cc" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
root@KubernetesMaster:/etc/cni/net.d#
```

On worker node NGINX is trying to come up but getting exited, I am not sure what's going on here - I am newbie to kubernetes & not able to fix this issue -

```
root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1

    root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
    94b2994401d0        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 1 second ago        Up Less than a second                       k8s_POD_nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default_677a722b-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_534
    5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
    5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
    f72500cae2b7        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 1 second ago        Up Less than a second                       k8s_POD_nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default_677a722b-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_585
    5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
    5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
    ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
```

I checked about /etc/cni/net.d & /opt/cni/bin on worker node as well, it is there -

```
root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# cd /etc/cni
root@kubernetesslave1:/etc/cni# ls -ltr
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 17 05:19 net.d
root@kubernetesslave1:/etc/cni# cd /opt/cni
root@kubernetesslave1:/opt/cni# ls -ltr
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 17 05:19 bin
root@kubernetesslave1:/opt/cni# cd bin
root@kubernetesslave1:/opt/cni/bin# ls -ltr
total 107440
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3890407 Aug 17  2017 bridge
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3475802 Aug 17  2017 ipvlan
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3520724 Aug 17  2017 macvlan
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3877986 Aug 17  2017 ptp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3475750 Aug 17  2017 vlan
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9921982 Aug 17  2017 dhcp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2605279 Aug 17  2017 sample
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 32351072 Mar 17 05:19 calico
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31490656 Mar 17 05:19 calico-ipam
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2856252 Mar 17 05:19 flannel
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3084347 Mar 17 05:19 loopback
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3036768 Mar 17 05:19 host-local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3550877 Mar 17 05:19 portmap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2850029 Mar 17 05:19 tuning
root@kubernetesslave1:/opt/cni/bin#
```

Answer (score 5):

I was using MicroK8s for a **production environment** and had the same problem.
I solved it by killing the calico pod on the node itself with `kubectl delete pod calico-node-nk4dg -n kube-system`

```bash
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide

# Output
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
...
calico-node-nk4dg                           1/1     Running   0             16d
...
```

Just to make it clear, this will automatically re-create the `Pod`.

Comment: Thanks, the same solution worked for my cluster running `flannel`. Deleting `kube-flannel-*` in the `kube-system` namespace resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with my GKE cluster on GCP with one of my preemptive node pools. Thanks to @mdaniel tip of checking the integrity of `/etc/cni/net.d` I could reproduce the issue again by ssh into the node of a testing cluster with the command `gcloud compute ssh <name of some node> --zone <zone-of-cluster> --internal-ip`. Then I simply edited the file `/etc/cni/net.d/10-gke-ptp.conflist` and messed with the values on the `"routes": [ {"dst": "0.0.0.0/0"} ]` (changed from `0.0.0.0/0` to `1.0.0.0/0`).

After that, I deleted the pods that were running inside of it and they all got stuck with the `ContainerCreating` status forever generating kublet events with the error `Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code...`

Note that in order to test I've set up my nodepool to have maximum of 1 node. Otherwise it will scale up a new one and the pods will be recreated at the new node. In my production incident the nodepool reached maximum node count so setting my tests to max 1 node reproduced a similar situation.

Since that, deleting the node from GKE solved the issue in production, I created a Python script that lists all events on the cluster and filters the ones that have the keyword `"Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code"`. Than I go over all events and get their pods, and then from the pods, I get the nodes. Finally I loop over the nodes deleting them both from Kubernetes API and from Compute API with it's respective Python clients. For the Python script I used the libs: `kubernetes` and `google-cloud-compute`.

### This is a simpler version of the script. Test it before using it:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
from google.cloud.compute_v1.services.instances import InstancesClient


ERROR_KEYWORDS = [
    'Failed to create pod sandbox'.lower()
]

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

events_result = v1.list_event_for_all_namespaces()

filtered_events = []

# filter only the events containing ERROR_KEYWORDS
for event in events_result.items:
    for error_keyword in ERROR_KEYWORDS:
        if error_keyword in event.message.lower():
            filtered_events.append(event)


# gets the list of pods from those events
pods_list = {}

for event in filtered_events:
    try:
        pod = v1.read_namespaced_pod(
            event.involved_object.name,
            namespace=event.involved_object.namespace
        )

        pod_dict = {
            "name": event.involved_object.name,
            "namespace": event.involved_object.namespace,
            "node": pod.spec.node_name
        }

        pods_list[event.involved_object.name] = pod_dict

    except Exception as e:
        pass


# Get the nodes from those pods
broken_nodes = set()

for name, pod_dict in pods_list.items():
    if pod_dict.get('node'):
        broken_nodes.add(pod_dict["node"])


broken_nodes = list(broken_nodes)

# Deletes the nodes from both Kubernetes API and Compute Engine API
if broken_nodes:
    broken_nodes_str = ", ".join(broken_nodes)
    print(f'BROKEN NODES: "{broken_nodes_str}"')
    for node in broken_nodes:

        try:
            api_response = v1.delete_node(node)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

        time.sleep(30)
        
        try:
            result = gcp_client.delete(project=PROJECT_ID, zone=CLUSTER_ZONE, instance=node)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

Answer (score 4):

```
kubectl drain node1 node2 --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets
```

Just when I was planning to expel pods on all nodes, I didn’t expect the pods with errors all the time to become Running. You can try to execute it, hope it will be useful to you

Answer (score 3):

This problem appeared for me when I added a PVC on AWS EKS.

Updating the aws-node CNI plugin to the latest version resolved it -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-vpc-cni.html

Comment: The link is outdated. Doesn't point to cni-upgrade documentation any more.

Answer (score 2):

AWS EKS doesn't yet support t3a, m5ad r5ad instances

Comment: true, and also the instances should be with good capacity else, it doesnt work

Comment: Pretty sure they're supported now. My answer is 2 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps resets kubernetes cluster and helped me to solve my problem.

1. Stop all running pods
2. Delete all worker nodes from cluster
3. Perform kubeadm reset on master and nodes
4. Initiate the master node
   kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address
5. install Pod network “WeaveNet”
   kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')&env.IPALLOC_RANGE=192.168.0.0/16"
6. Join nodes to the cluster
7. Restart all nodes

Answer (score 1):

```
#-------------------------------------
#Reset the kubernetes environment
#-----------------------------------
#[root@centos8-Master: ~]# k get nodes
#NAME             STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
#centos8-master   Ready    control-plane   14m   v1.24.1
#centos8-slave    Ready    <none>          11m   v1.24.3
#

#Master Node
#1. Delete the nodes
#First delete all pods, deployments, svc 
#kubectl delete --all pods
#kubectl delete --all deployments
#kubectl delete --all svc
#kubectl drain centos8-slave --ignore-daemonsets --delete-emptydir-data --force
#kubectl delete node centos8-slave
#
#Worker Node
#2. Go to worker node, stop all the kubelet services.
#[root@centos8-Slave rprasads]# kubectl version --short
#Client Version: v1.24.3
#Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
#[root@centos8-Slave rprasads]# systemctl stop kubelet
#[root@centos8-Slave rprasads]# netstat -tulnp |grep kube
#kill -9 <pid> [kube-proxy]
#
#Master Node
#2. Reset the kubeadm.
#$ sudo kubeadm reset
#$ sudo swapoff -a 
#
#Master Node
#3. Get you kubeadm version
#[root@centos8-Master: ~]# kubectl version --short
#Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
#Client Version: v1.24.1
#Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
#Server Version: v1.24.3
#
#Master Node
#4.On Master Initialize the kubeadm with proper network address and version
#$ kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.101 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16

##Download calico yaml file from the site: Refer the documentation https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/getting-started/kubernetes/self-managed-onprem/onpremises#install-calico-with-kubernetes-api-datastore-more-than-50-nodes
#
#$ curl https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/manifests/calico.yaml -O
#$ kubectl apply -f calico.yaml
#
#Worker Node
#5. Go to worker node and add the node with the command displayed.
# kubeadm join 192.168.56.101:6443 --token h0nuxq.zk9m731nc4ia93pq --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:1682644baf3433caeb0e6f9099ed487ef48b94ab6a0314df88e3ff42ae501a13
#
#Master Node 
#6.On the master node run below commands.
#$ sudo rm -rf $HOME/.kube
#
#$ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
#$ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
#$ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
#
#$ sudo systemctl enable docker.service
#$ sudo service kubelet restart
#
#$ kubectl get nodes
#
#
#------------------------------------------------
#Test your new kubernetes cluster environment.
#-----------------------------------------------
#[root@centos8-Master: ~]# kubectl run nginx --image=nginx
#Wait for some time.
#
#[root@centos8-Master: ~]# k describe pods nginx
#Normal  Scheduled  21s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx to centos8-slave
#
#[root@centos8-Master: ~]# k get pods
#NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
#nginx   1/1     Running   0          25s
#
#*************************************END*************************************
```

Comment: I recently upgraded my kubernetes version from 18,.1.0 to 24.1.3 and after that everything stop working. I followed the above reset steps to bring my kubernetes cluster back and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error after removing apparmor daemon from the systems.

As soon as apparmor was reinstalled the containers started.

I think it has something to with that these containers set the SYS_ADMIN cap and without armor this was not allowed. But I'm not sure.

```
   securityContext:
      capabilities:
        drop:
          - all
        add:
          - SYS_ADMIN
```